# Which cookies are transferred with 'withCredentials' API in ReactJS and how to limit them?

Tags: reactjs, api, cookies

When looking at the Cookie request header, which cookies are included if you're using withCredentials?

An API call that we rely on requires a specific cookie to be transferred, however when using withCredentials it seems to include a lot of Cookies.  Is there a way to limit this?

Comment: You can grab the specific cookie on the backend, why would you limit the cookie to 1? Otherwise you can set that specific cookie `httpOnly` to `false` and let the hackers have an easier time, but at least you can select it on the frontend and send it in the headers.